# Facebook: Custom login button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-login

I would like to design a custom login button for facebook login similar to one shown below

http://dribbble.com/shots/190494-Log-in-with-Facebook
[image]

The primary objective is to be in sync with the site’s theme.

Is this acceptable to Facebook’s TOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow Facebook's TOS to the letter, you need a small light blue line toward the bottom of the "f".

From Facebook's [Brand PermissionS Center](https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php)

> While you may scale the size to suit your needs, you may not modify the “f” logo in any other way (such as by changing the design or color).